# Configure a Hyper-V machine with DockerNAT including internet access

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

How can I use the DockerNAT virtual switch for an Hyper-V VM so it can 'talk' to other docker containers and enable internet access as in the MobyLinux VM?

Long story:

I want to install [Univention](https://www.univention.de/) on my Windows Server host via Hyper-V. On my host an nginx docker container is also running as a proxy. If someone calls `univention.domain.com` it should automatically redirect to my hyper-v Univention VM. This works when I set the network adapter of the Hyper-V machine to the `DockerNAT` and then give it the IP Address `10.0.75.100` as the Gateway address of the DockerNAT is `10.0.75.1` and the IP Address of the MobyLinux is `10.0.75.2`. When I now ping `10.0.75.100` from my nginx container it works.

But as Univention needs an internet connection to install applications I'm not quite satisfied with this configuration as I am not able to connect to the internet when I use the `DockerNAT` network interface.

Then on the other hand I am able to ping from the nginx container (running as a linux container in the hyper-v VM of MobyLinux) f.e. `8.8.8.8`. So the MobyLinux container created by Docker has to have internet access, right? Although it also uses the `DockerNAT` interface. But its set as an 'internal' virtual switch and the connection of my main NIC isn't marked as 'shared'.

p.s.: I am aware that there is a Univention docker image but Univention started to use docker for it's apps. So I can't run most of their apps in the app store, as docker container in docker container doesn't fit well (Univention can't enable docker due to network problems)

---

```
 Windows Server 2019 17623
 Docker 18.04.0-ce-rc2
```